# Is Docker right for my use case?

Tags: docker

We need a way to efficiently and robustly push updates out to our users out in the field, who all have identical Ubuntu boxes provided by us. We also need something that as we upgrade the OS (we are way overdue for a Ubuntu upgrade as you can tell) we can feel relatively secure about our packages "just working".

I initially thought Docker, but the more I thought about it I felt like maybe it wasn't, as these boxes are ours we control the OS on it which is a big part of the value proposition of Docker, or so I understand. So if we KNOW our boxes will always be Ubuntu and we basically just have a Django app plus some processes to run, is Docker any better than a deb package?

TL;DR: Docker vs deb packages for a distributed appliance that will always run Ubuntu so platform independence is not that important.

Comment: Also see [rkt](https://coreos.com/rkt), which is (at least IMO) more sysadmin friendly, and doesn't want to take over the system. Or `systemd-nspawn`, if you will be running systemd.

Comment: Thank you for your help, derobert, and thank you to the other mods why reminding me why I don't often use SE. Feel free to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Containers are nice that you are forced to package up your application and its dependencies together, and basically are forced to automate it. Then it's relatively easy to fire up one (or more) on a machine, automatically.

This can help with upgrades. Back to that in a moment.

> We need a way to efficiently and robustly push updates out to our users out in the field.

Docker and rkt both have their own container stores; rkt at least also offers full cryptographic integrity checking. Docker containers are built in layers, which provides some efficiency (only need to pull changed layers). `rkt` currently pulls a full image each time, or at least does in the version I have installed.

It's possible to convert images between the two—for example, on a recent project here I use Docker for development (because the layers can help a lot there), then convert the image to rkt for deployment (because rkt is more sysadmin friendly and less of a security worry, at least to me).

Note that both of these technologies are rapidly developing currently. The container format, for example, is changing. So you should expect to be doing frequent upgrades if you decide on Docker or rkt.

BTW: All your dependencies are packaged in the container, so the version of the OS running outside the container is less important. But you'd typically ship a new container for *every* update. That can consume a fair bit of bandwidth.

> We also need something that as we upgrade the OS (we are way overdue for a Ubuntu upgrade as you can tell) we can feel relatively secure about our packages "just working".

What you need here is a test lab. Confidence that an upgrade will work should mainly come from the fact that you've *tested it*, repeatedly, in all the variations you support.

Containers can help—you can use them to automatically run tests (as an example, see GitLab's automated test setup). Containers are fairly lightweight, as far as host resources go, much more so than VMs. So you can test often—even every commit. And should run the tests using the same automated scripts that build the containers you'd ship, so you can be confident your container image works.

But for the actual base OS upgrades, you're going to need to test that on actual hardware. You can test OS upgrades with VMs too (which is nice, since you can then very easily rollback the image—and you can automate that), but you need to test the actual hardware too. Especially since they're in the field and that upgrade failing is probably expensive.

**In short:** containers are useful for a lot of stuff like this, but I'm don't think the software is yet mature enough that I'd be comfortable depending on its stability through the next 5 years. I expect that within a year or two, though, that will change so it's a good idea to be thinking about this now.

PS: A non-technical thing to consider: If you're downloading packages from the Ubuntu archives, Ubuntu is likely handling your GPL compliance by having source available from the same place. If you ship container images, you have to worry about that. (Of course, you also should be doing this when shipping the machines.)

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer; we definitely do test, I guess what I meant mostly by that is that the solution should help with that and not need a lot of work on the solution's part if everything else is in order.

Comment: @AlbertoSancho I haven't used Docker Swarm. So can't really comment on it. But I'd definitely look into the maturity of it (and how hard upgrading the swarm is). Also most container management systems are for "we need sufficient copies of this container running *somewhere*"—but it sounds like you need it running on particular boxes (e.g., on each client's box).